# How can you tell if invitations have been sent for a meeting in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am writing a COM add-in for Outlook using C#.  If a meeting was saved and invitations were not sent, Outlook puts a message at the top of the form saying the invitations have not been sent.  How do I determine programmatically that invitations have not been sent for a meeting?

I tried examining each `Recipient` and checking the `MeetingResponseStatus`.  I would expect it to be `OlResponseNone` if the invitation has not been sent but `OlResponseNotResponded` if the invitations have been sent but no responses have been received.  However, I always get `OlResponseNone` for recipients that either haven't been sent an invitation or that have but have not yet reponded.  I therefore can't tell apart a meeting where invitations haven't been sent from one where they have been sent but no one has responded.

I've done most of my testing in Outlook 2007, but I believe the same holds true for 2003 and 2010, all of which I need to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a partial answer in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/f3daa63c-19ed-45ea-b8e3-8531e1764a01/).  I need to read the DASL property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/80BE0102".  In Outlook 2007 and leter, you can do this with a PropertyAccessor as follows:

```
appointment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/80BE0102");
```

However, I need to also support Outlook 2003, and the PropertyAccessor property was added in Outlook 2007.  I was therefore able to use [Redemption's RDOMail object](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) with the following code (error handling omitted).

```
var _session = New RDOSession();
_session.Logon();
var _message = _session.GetMessageFromID(appointment.EntryID, ((Outlook.MAPIFolder)appointment.Parent).StoreID);
return (bool)_message.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8229000B"];
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_message);
_session.Logoff();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_session);
```