# Check for appointment items that have been updated after the initial sent invitation

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I have an Outlook plugin that is tied to the item send event. When the user clicks send, I get a list of recipients and I check for external addresses.
I need to be able to distinguish Outlook appointment items that have been updated after the original item was sent.

Is there a DASL property, a Redemption property or an standard appointment item property to determine this?

For mailitems, I check the length of the ConversationIndex string , if the length is 44, I know it’s a new message. If greater than 44, I know it’s a reply or forward.

```
//for example
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
string convID = mailItem.ConversationIndex;
if ((convID.Length = 44)) //new messages are always 44 
{ //do something }
```

I’m looking to do a similar check on new appointment items but the conversation index does not increase for appointment items.

This question [- link -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117841/how-can-you-tell-if-invitations-have-been-sent-for-a-meeting-in-outlook) is similar but not the same because the FInvited DASL property is always true after the item has been sent.

Comment: Can you search the Sent Items folder for the invitations with the same global appointment id?

Comment: That's another option I didn't consider. I'll try that as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to check the new meeting/appointment items by subscribing to the Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler event and when this event is fired you can then check the fInvited DASL property. Since this event fires before the ItemSend event, I always know the current item's fInvited value.

Here's an example that I hope helps someone else in the future:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            olInspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
            olInspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Compose_New_Message_Inspector);

        }

        public bool AppointmentSent { get; set; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            void Compose_New_Message_Inspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
            {
                try
                {
                    var Item = Inspector.CurrentItem;
                    if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
                    {
                       //not concerned with mail items 
                    }
                    else if (Item is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                    {
                       
                        // added to check if an appontment is new or if it's beeing updated or has alredy been sent
                        // fInvited=false if meeting is newly composed and true if it has already been sent  
                        Outlook.AppointmentItem apptItem = Item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
                        bool fInvited;
                        try
                        {
                            fInvited = apptItem.PropertyAccessor.
                                GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8229000B");
                            Debug.WriteLine("fInvited =" + fInvited);
                            AppointmentSent = fInvited;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            if (apptItem != null)
                            {
                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(apptItem);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }

                    }

                    // To hangle right-click action (Forward Meeting or Foward occurrences) 
                    // fInvited=false if meeting is newly composed and true if it has already been sent  
                    else if (Item is Outlook.MeetingItem)
                    {
                        Outlook.MeetingItem meetingItem = Item as Outlook.MeetingItem;
                        bool fInvited;
                        try
                        {
                            fInvited = meetingItem.PropertyAccessor.
                                GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8229000B");
                            Debug.WriteLine("fInvited =" + fInvited);
                            AppointmentSent = fInvited;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            if (meetingItem != null)
                            {
                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(meetingItem);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }

                    }

                    try
                    {
                        if (Item != null)
                        {
                            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Item);
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
```